# Is it possible to use SYSDATE as a column alias?

Tags: oracle, alias, sysdate

If I want to run a report daily and store the report's date as one of the column headers. Is this possible?

Example output (Counting the activities of employees for that day):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, COUNT(ACTIVITY) AS "Activity_On_SYSDATE" FROM EMPLOYEE_ACCESS GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME;

Employee      Activity_On_17042016
Jane          5
Martha        8
Sam           11
```

Comment: It can be used as an alias, but it would not be extrapolated the way you are expecting it to, and would just remain as the word "SYSDATE"

Comment: I see that SYSDATE itself cannot be used. Is there a way to get the current date then without the use of SYSDATE?

Comment: You could dynamically build the query so that the alias was dynamic.  Exactly how you would do that will depend on what sort of report we're talking about.  Are you using a reporting application?  Generating a text report using `SQL*Plus`?  Something else?

Comment: No reporting application. It's directly from the Select statement through oracle

Comment: "directl ... through oracle" doesn't tell us which client you are using; SQL\*Plus? SQL Deveoper? Apex? Something else? And will this always be run through the same client? Basically, you can't do this through plain SQL but you may be able to (ab)use features of your client to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to do a reporting job with a data storing tool. The database (and SQL) is for storing and retrieving data, not for creating reports. There are special tools for creating reports.

In database design, it is very unhealthy to encode actual data in table or column name. Neither a table name nor a column name should have, as part of the name (and of the way they are used), an employee id, a date, or any other bit of actual data. Actual data should only be in fields, which in turn are in columns in different tables.

From what you describe, your base table should have columns for employee, activity and date. Then on any given day, if you want the count for the "current" day, you can query with

```
select   employee, count(activity) ct 
from     table_name  
where    activity_date = SYSDATE 
group by employee
```

If you want, you can also include the "activity_date" column in the output, that will show for which date the report was run.

Note that I assumed the column name for "date" is "activity_date." And in the output I used "ct" for a column alias, not "count."  DATE and COUNT are reserved words, like SYSDATE, and you should NOT use them as table or column name. You could use them as aliases, as long as you don't need to refer to these aliases anywhere else in SQL, but it is still a very bad idea. Imagine you ever need to refer to a column (by name or by alias) and the name or alias is SYSDATE. What would a where clause like this mean?

```
where sysdate = sysdate
```

Do you see the problem?

Also, I can't tell from your question - were you thinking of storing these reports back in the database? To what end? It is better to store just one query and run it whenever needed (and make the "activity_date" for which you want the counts) an input parameter, so you can run the query for any date, at any time in the future. There is no need to store the actual daily reports in the database, as long as the base table is properly maintained.

Good luck!